# android: how to elegantly set many button IDs

Tags: android, view

I have many buttons in my activity (only a subset of which are visible at a time).  I currently have something ugly like this:

```
buttonID[0] = R.id.buttonr1b1;
buttonID[1] = R.id.buttonr1b2;
buttonID[2] = R.id.buttonr1b3;
buttonID[3] = R.id.buttonr1b4;
...
buttonID[35] = R.id.buttonr1b36;

for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    button[i] = (Button) findViewById(buttonID[i]);
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to reference all of R.id.buttonXXX ?  It just looks so wrong and ugly.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your instincts are correct. It's ugly and in general if you find yourself wanting to do this you should rethink your design.

If your buttons are uniform to the point where you want to loop over them to do something like this, they're probably uniform enough to generate programmatically in the first place (and you can store references as you create them) or use some form of `AdapterView`. What data needs to be associated with each button? Can you associate it directly using setTag/getTag? Do you need to use IDs here at all?

Comment: Quite possibly, but if the number of views is constant and the data never changes it may be overkill.

Comment: I'll look at setTag/getTag this weekend.  This looks like good advice.  Thank you.

Comment: Be aware that you probably want the single-argument setTag, not the overload that takes an ID key. There are some gotchas to the one that takes a key.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is more elegant or less elegant, because you will lose compile-time checking of your IDs. However, you can construct the IDs by name:

```
final static String PREFIX = "buttonr1b";
...
Resources res = getResources();
for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
    int resID = res.getIdentifier(PREFIX + i , "id", getPackageName());
    button[i] = (Button) findViewById(resID);
}
```

Note: make sure "getPackageName()" would return the appropriate package for your R class, otherwise specify it explicitly.

Comment: This is a very specific answer to my specific question.  Thank you.

Comment: Actually, just a small clarification.  To get the button ID, it looks more like res.getIdentifier(PREFIX + i , "id", getPackageName());