# Can I put this into a for loop?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, for-loop, r.java-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android: how to elegantly set many button IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536791/android-how-to-elegantly-set-many-button-ids)

This is an android program made with eclipse. I've tried using string concatenation in the place of imageButton1 to no avail. R is the generated class so I cannot go into it and edit it so that the imageButtons are part of an array. 
How can I put this into a for loop?

```
    seatButton[0] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    seatButton[1] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    seatButton[2] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    seatButton[3] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    seatButton[4] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    seatButton[5] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    seatButton[6] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    seatButton[7] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);
    seatButton[8] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton9);
    seatButton[9] = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536791/android-how-to-elegantly-set-many-button-ids)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use `getResources().getIdentifier(String name, String defType, String defPackage)` where name is the resource name, defType is drawable and defPackage is your full package name.
Which would result in something like:

> ```
> for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
>     int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("imageButton" + (i + 1), "id", your_package");
>     seatButton[i] = (ImageButton) findViewById(resId);
> }
> ```

Answer (score 5):

You can, one approach is the following:

```
ImageButton[] btns = {R.id.imageButton1, R.id.imageButton2, ..., R.id.imageButton10};
for(int i = 0, len = btns.length; i < len; i++) {
    seatButton[i] = (ImageButton) findByViewId(btns[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about your application or about android, but you could use runtime reflection (although it should not be used if you can avoid it, in my opinion).

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

...

for(int i=1; ; i++) {
    try {
        Field f = R.id.getClass().getField("imageButton" + i);
        seatButton[i-1] = (ImageButton) findByViewId(f.get(R.id)); // Add cast to whatever type R.id.imageButton<i> is
    } catch (Exception e) {
        break;
    }
}
```