# Managing several EditTexts in Android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android: how to elegantly set many button IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536791/android-how-to-elegantly-set-many-button-ids)

Everyone.

I'm trying to build my first Android app for doing some RMS (Root Mean Square) error calculation. For this I need several experimental points inputs, this is done manually in EditTexts. So I have 40 EditTexts in one layout. The problem is when it comes to managing them, I have something like this:

```
public class InsertarData extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
EditText x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12,x13,x14,x15,x16,x17;
EditText y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8,y9,y10,y11,y12,y13,y14,y15,y16,y17;
float [] datosX;
float [] datosY;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.insertardatos);
    x1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x1Et);
    x2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x2Et);
    x3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x3Et);
    x4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x4Et);
    x5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x5Et);
    x6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x6Et);
    x7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x7Et);
    x8=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x8Et);
    x9=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x9Et);
    x10=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x10Et);
    x11=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x11Et);
    x12=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x12Et);
    x13=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x13Et);
    x14=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x14Et);
    x15=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x15Et);
    x16=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x17Et);
    x17=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.x17Et);

    y1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y1Et);
    y2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y2Et);
    y3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y3Et);
    y4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y4Et);
    y5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y5Et);
    y6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y6Et);
    y7=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y7Et);
    y8=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y8Et);
    y9=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y9Et);
   y10=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y10Et);
   y11=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y11Et);
   y12=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y12Et);
   y13=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y13Et);
   y14=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y14Et);
   y15=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y15Et);
   y16=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y16Et);
   y17=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.y17Et);

   Button continuar=(Button)findViewById(R.id.continuarBtn);
   continuar.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View e) {
    switch(e.getId()){
        case R.id.continuarBtn:{
        datosX=new float[17];
        datosX[0]=Float.parseFloat(x1.getText().toString());
        datosX[1]=Float.parseFloat(x2.getText().toString());
        datosX[2]=Float.parseFloat(x3.getText().toString());
        datosX[3]=Float.parseFloat(x4.getText().toString());
        datosX[4]=Float.parseFloat(x5.getText().toString());
        datosX[5]=Float.parseFloat(x6.getText().toString());
        datosX[6]=Float.parseFloat(x7.getText().toString());
        datosX[7]=Float.parseFloat(x8.getText().toString());
        datosX[8]=Float.parseFloat(x9.getText().toString());
        datosX[9]=Float.parseFloat(x10.getText().toString());
        datosX[10]=Float.parseFloat(x11.getText().toString());
        datosX[11]=Float.parseFloat(x12.getText().toString());
        datosX[12]=Float.parseFloat(x13.getText().toString());
        datosX[13]=Float.parseFloat(x14.getText().toString());
        datosX[14]=Float.parseFloat(x15.getText().toString());
        datosX[15]=Float.parseFloat(x16.getText().toString());
        datosX[16]=Float.parseFloat(x17.getText().toString());

        datosY[0]=Float.parseFloat(y1.getText().toString());
        datosY[1]=Float.parseFloat(y2.getText().toString());
        datosY[2]=Float.parseFloat(y3.getText().toString());
        datosY[3]=Float.parseFloat(y4.getText().toString());
        datosY[4]=Float.parseFloat(y5.getText().toString());
        datosY[5]=Float.parseFloat(y6.getText().toString());
        datosY[6]=Float.parseFloat(y7.getText().toString());
        datosY[7]=Float.parseFloat(y8.getText().toString());
        datosY[8]=Float.parseFloat(y9.getText().toString());
        datosY[9]=Float.parseFloat(y10.getText().toString());
        datosY[10]=Float.parseFloat(y11.getText().toString());
        datosY[11]=Float.parseFloat(y12.getText().toString());
        datosY[12]=Float.parseFloat(y13.getText().toString());
        datosY[13]=Float.parseFloat(y14.getText().toString());
        datosY[14]=Float.parseFloat(y15.getText().toString());
        datosY[15]=Float.parseFloat(y16.getText().toString());
        datosY[16]=Float.parseFloat(y17.getText().toString());

        }
        }
    }

}
```

This "works" (it needs to be completed passing the datosX and datosY to another activity. But, before, I need to know whether the EditTexts are empty or not and I cannot imagine doing something like if(edittext.getText().toString()!=null) before every parseFloat.

Is there any better way to manage a lot of EditTexts and know if they're empty or not? I've though of an array of EditText and doing something like:

```
EditText editarray[17];
editarray[0]=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext0);
```

Is this the way of doing it?

Thank you very much for reading and answering in advance. Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
EditText xE, yE;

float x, y;

int[] xIds = { R.id.x1et, R.id.x2et, /*...etc*/ };
int[] yIds = { R.id.y1et, R.id.y2et, /*...etc*/ };

for(int i = 0; i < xIds.length && i < yIds.length; i++) {
    xE = (EditText)findViewById(xIds[i]);
    yE = (EditText)findViewById(yIds[i]);
    try { 
        x = Float.parseFloat(xE.getText().toString());
        y = Float.parseFloat(yE.getText().toString());
        //do whatever you need with the data here
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        //Either there was an invalid input, or field was empty
        //You can add extra logic here to check them for empty fields
        //or just exit the loop here
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I'll go this way, it's JUST what I needed and was thinking of doing, but I didn't know how to setup the array.

You guys are awesome, Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Are these EditText controls below each other? If so, I'd use a ListView, and have a separate row for every EditText. Then, it'd be easier to handle this many EditTexts in the list's adapter. It'd also require less memory, since the ListView is virtualized. But I guess the UI would be just terrible to use.

Comment: Yes, they are different. And I have them just as you say, a TableLayout and 2 EditText for each row, two columns, each for X and Y.

What I wanted yo know if there's a better way to parse all the EditTexts into floats --and know from which EditText they start to be empty--

Thanks!

Comment: +1 for mentioning memory management

Answer (score 1):

you can get the id of the view by using resources, it becomes easier to manage multiple views like this. yes, array seems is a good solution to manage the edit texts like this.

to access your 1st editText, assuming you gave the id of the editText as `edittext0` then you can get access to it by.

```
int idsArray[40];
for(int i=0; i<40; i++){
  String textString =  "edittext" + Integer.toString(i);
  int editId = getResources.getIdentifier(textString, "id", getPackageName());
  // store the id's in an array
  idsArray[i] = editId;
}
```

you can use the same method to get access to your editText.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(idsArray[i]);
```

to get access to each edit text in your layout and then check if the editText has data.

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate over layout's children and determine which of them are EditText

Layout with your EditText widgets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<EditText  
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<EditText  
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Iteration:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);

    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        Log.i("tag", child.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```