# Handle drawables - by the name

Tags: android, image, drawable

I already know how to handle drawables like this:

```
final int[] imgSizeIds = new int[]{
  R.drawable.zero,R.drawable.one,R.drawable.two,
  ...
};
```

and

```
setImageResource(imgSizeIds [ size ] );
```

in android.  But what If I have an Array of Strings that is populated like this:

```
String[] names = new String[]{"oliver", "peter", "mike"};
```

and I would like to use Image oliver.jpg when The ROW Oliver is going to be handled.

Something like:

```
setImageResource(R.drawable. (AND HERE COMES "oliver") );
```

So the result will be:

```
setImageResource(R.drawable.oliver);
```

Two Arrays would not be the big problem but I also do not know how to put a string into the integer Array of drawables.. I cannot do something like:

```
final int[10] imgSizeIds; 
String stringy = "oliver"; 
int[0] = "R.drawable." + stringy;
```

So that the 1st item in that array would be set to `R.drawable.oliver`

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536791/android-how-to-elegantly-set-many-button-ids) seems to be the compact version of your question... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
int resid = getResources.getIdentifier("oliver" , "drawable", getPackageName());
setImageResource(resid);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I try to use it but with the 1st lane I get getResources. as a error in eclipse sayn : getresources cannot be resolved... no idea whats wrong... the calss extends BaseAdapter = could that be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

```
setImageResource(R.drawable. (AND HERE COMES "oliver") );
```

So the result will be: `setImageResource(R.drawable.oliver);`

this will probably not happen.Because when you tell android to take a string specified in a String variable,it would take it as - "oliver" and put it like `R.drawable."oliver"`  or even though,if you would try putting it like - `setImageResource("R.drawable."+ (AND HERE COMES "oliver") )` it will take it as a String like "R.drawable.oliver" which is after all a String variable and not appropriate to be passed in `setImageResource()` method.

Be sure that R.drawable.imagename gives you `int`, not a string.

Answer (score 0):

See if below code helps-

```
String[] imgNames = new String[]{ "oliver", "apple", "car"};
```

and use this to use names from name string array-

```
ImageView imgvw = (ImageView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(imgNames[index],"drawable",getPackageName()));
```

where index is position of item in string name array.