# use string/array to get file (android)

Tags: java, android, arrays, image

I have an issue with grabbing an image dynamicly. Simply put, how can I do something like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_place);
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_string[1]);
```

So basicly, the image_string could hold anything,

image1
image2
image3

Must be possible, but can't figure out how.

Comment: what you want to implement exactly?

Comment: I think you're searching for [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536791/android-how-to-elegantly-set-many-button-ids). [The answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536791/android-how-to-elegantly-set-many-button-ids/7536890#7536890) explains how to get resources by a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this,

```
public static Integer[] images = new Integer[]{R.drawable.my_love,R.drawable.first,R.drawable.second,R.drawable.third};
```

And then set the image resource like this,

```
ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(this.context);
mImageView.setImageResource(this.images[position]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get Resources by name.
like this:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_place);
int resource = getResources().getIdentifier(image_string[0], "drawable", "com.package");
img.setImageResource(resource);
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer, surprised no one has upvoted yet.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that image_string was an [XML string array](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/arrays.html), you could do the following:

```
String[] image_string = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_string);
```

And then access elements like a normal array.

However, [setImageResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) takes the ID of a resource, not a string.

So to get the ID, you would do something like:

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_place);
String[] image_string = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.image_string);
img.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(image_string[1] , "drawable", getPackageName()));
```